# Loading a hashtable with File Names and Sizes

Tags: powershell

I want to load a hashtable with File Names and Sizes, so I did this:

```
#Get files 
$htA = dir | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "\.output\.[A-Z]-[0-9]\.csv"} | ft name, @{Label=”Size” ; Expression = {$_.Length}}
```

It succeeds in loading file name and size, but when I try to read the table with a foreach in this way:

```
$htA.Keys | % {
    #Output to a text file
    "key = $_ , value = " + $htA.Item($_) | format-table -AutoSize >> "C:\psTest\test1.txt"
}
```

It doesn't find the key, and instead I get this output:

**key =  , value = Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData**

I'm pretty new at this so any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

generally speaking, you shouldn't use `format` commands if you want to perform manipulations with data, only perform those commands when you've done all the manipulations and want to look at the data

```
$htA = dir | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "\.output\.[A-Z]-[0-9]\.csv"} | select name,length
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.  I was able to loop using this:  `foreach ($h in $htA.GetEnumerator()) {
    Write-Host "$($h.Name): $($h.length)"
}`